# How to set the $scope to a specific MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

On certain pages I want to change the $scope from being data (All database documents) to just a specific one based on what the url of the page is.

My initial controller to get the data in the database is

factory.js

```
    acquiApp.factory('acquiFactory' , function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get(companyURL);
        }
    }
});
```

controller.js

```
 acquiApp.controller('dataAccessController' , ['$scope' , '$http' , 'acquiFactory', function($scope , $http , acquiFactory) {
    acquiFactory.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {

            })
            $scope.companys = data;
        });
}]);
```

I want to search the data if company.name is equal to:

```
$location.path().replace('/' , '')
```

I'm not seeing how I can search the data and reset the scope so in the application I can call {{company.name}} and It will changed based on the URL. I've thought about using $filter but I was looking on here to see if there was a better approach and to learn.

Comment: What is present inside data?

Comment: @Vivz An Array of Objects from the database. So the objects are structured like company.name company.decsription

Comment: And what does $location.path().replace('/' , '') return , an array of  names that u want to match with company.name?

Comment: @Vivz It returns the URL path after the /. So $location.path() on a site called test.com/Microsoft would return /Microsoft

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question... Do you want to search if $location.path().replace('/' , '') value is present inside data?

Comment: @Vivz Inside one of the objects inside data yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do search like this

```
 acquiApp.controller('dataAccessController' , ['$scope' , '$http' , 'acquiFactory', function($scope , $http , acquiFactory) {
    acquiFactory.get()
        .success(function(data) {
         var val=$location.path().replace('/' , '');
            angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
              if(value.name==val)
                 $scope.companys = value.name;
            })
        });
}]);
```